# How to write custom function to validate relation table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, First `auction` table that has a `price` column, and second `bid` table that has `amount` column.`bid` table have foreign key called `auction_id`.
I need to write a function before insert new row into `bid` table, that function should validates the `bid amount` must be greater than the `auction price`.

Comment: Shouldn't your application check that first any way?  If the bidder enters a price that's too low, you should gracefully handle that scenario, rather than raising an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bid_func() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE 
    p NUMERIC;
    query TEXT;
BEGIN
    query := format('SELECT price FROM %I WHERE id = %L', 'auction', NEW.auction_id);
    EXECUTE query INTO p;
    IF NEW.amount < p THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'bid amount must be greater than auction price!!';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: The dynamic SQL is completely unnecessary. You can replace that with `select price into p from auction where id = new.auction_id;` (and remove the `execute query...`)

Comment: i agree with @a_horse_with_no_name also the dynamic SQL can be a extra location where securcy can be possibly compromised by a SQL injection.. If you don't protect it with  `quote_ident(..)` or  `quote_literal(..)`  depending on the usage .

Answer (score 0):

you can perhaps write a price into the bid table as well, it's heavier on the size, but doesn't require trigger and input check will be much faster as it doesn't require additional lookup.

```sql
CREATE TABLE auction (
  auction_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  price money NOT NULL
);
-- requires extra idx as well
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON auction (auction_id, price);

CREATE TABLE bid (
  bid_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  auction_id int NOT NULL,
  price money NOT NULL,
  bid money NOT NULL CHECK (bid > price),
  FOREIGN KEY (auction_id, price) REFERENCES auction (auction_id, price) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this..**

**Insert using select statement**

```
insert into bid 
  select <auction_id>, amount
  from auction 
  where auction_id = <auction_Id> and price < amount
```

Comment: If this fails to insert the row, it fails silently. You need to include how to check if the insert succeeded as part of your answer.

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie, there was a typo error. Now its working fine.

Comment: @MatBailie when you insert row into any table  from console then database shows the count of how much rows inserted.

Comment: That's not any help when you're inserting a row programmatically (from an application, rather than from a console).

Comment: @MatBailie every orm tool/ library return the query execution status. In case of insertion too.